# Mercadolibre API

Tags: json, api, curl

I'm working with the MercadoLibre API, and I have an issue to directly get the new item id from mercadolibre (http://developers.mercadolibre.com/relist-your-items/)

If I repost an item I can get the new id without any problems, but if the repost is directly made by Mercadolibre then I'm unable to get the new id from the republished item. I was thinking to search for it by name https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLU/search?q=title, then filter it by seller but I'd like to know if there is any other way to directly manage this from the MercadoLibre Api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the item that is finalized mercadolibre they call it father item, and the new republication would be the son. There is no way to identify a child from a parent. If you have a way to do it backwards, that is, in the child item you have the field parent_item_id that would be the parent ID that was finalized.

You have to keep in mind that if the field seller_custom_field is completed to add a SKU to the item, the same field is maintained for the child item, they can use it as a guide. A resource that can be useful: https://api.mercadolibre.com/items?ids={item_id}&attributes=parent_item_id,id

PD: By mercadolibre team